# Integration over region yields wrong answer?

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

From an electricity and magnetism question, I want to evaluate:
\begin{equation}
E = \frac{k}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_{-d}^{d} \int_{-d}^{d} \frac{-y^2}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} dx dy
\end{equation}
Does using Mathematica's $\verb!Integrate!$ like:
\begin{equation}
\verb!-k/(4 Pi! \ \epsilon \verb!) * Integrate[-y^2/((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2)), {x, y}! \ \in \verb!Rectangle[{-d, d}, {-d, d}]]!
\end{equation} over the 2D rectangle surface work? Because when I've used it, it seems to give the wrong answer. This is what it should be: Here is what the right answer should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZsLO.jpg

Answer (score 6):

You are specifying the [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) wrong. It should be `Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]`

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll[x, y, z, d];
integrand = -y^2/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2);
Assuming[d > 0, Integrate[integrand,
   {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-d, -d}, {d, d}]] // FullSimplify]

(* -4 z Sqrt[(d^2 + z^2)/(2 d^2 + z^2)] Sqrt[1 + d^2/(d^2 + z^2)]
   ArcCot[(d z)/(d^2 + z^2 - d Sqrt[2 d^2 + z^2])] - 
 4 d ArcSinh[d/Sqrt[d^2 + z^2]] + 
 4 Sqrt[1 + d^2/z^2] z Sqrt[z^2/(d^2 + z^2)] ArcTan[z/d] *)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't catch that reading the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The result seems to be wrong. But more analysis might be needed.

Comparing it with the explicit integrate shows the difference.

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, d];
integrand = -y^2/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2);
Integrate[integrand, {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-d, d}, {-d, d}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
Integrate[integrand, {x, -d, d}, GenerateConditions -> False]
Integrate[%, {y, -d, d}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've used `GenerateConditions -> False` to speed it up, else it was taking forever.

The above result looks closer to what you show in the link. May be more simplification is needed.

[image]

---

**Update**

Ah, I see now from Bob answer that the OP used the wrong syntax for Rectangle (I also did not notice and just copied the code as is).

But this means there is a bug!  Since the Rectangle area is now zero, hence the result of the integration should be zero! But it is not.

```
ClearAll[x, y, d, r];
Integrate[-y^2/((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2)), {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-d, d}, {-d, d}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To show this, lets try this simpler one

```
ClearAll[x, y, d, r];
Integrate[-y^2/x^(3/2), {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-d, d}, {-d, d}]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
ClearAll[x, y, d, r];
Integrate[-y^2/x^(3/2), {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-d, d}, {-r, r}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[%, r -> d]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the integral should be zero. This looks like a bug to me. Integration over zero area should be zero.

I also noticed that `Area` command does not say area is zero, but undefined. May be this has something to do with it.

```
d = 1;
Area@Rectangle[{-d, d}, {-d, d}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Area@Rectangle[{-d, -d}, {d, d}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]